# Combining two files of floats into a single file in C

Tags: c, arrays

My task is to read from two files both containing floats. Then I have to put them in a new file in an ascending order. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int numLines(const char * fileName){
    FILE *file=fopen(fileName,"r");
    int lines=0;
    char c;
    while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
        if(c==10){
            lines++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return lines;
}

float *  fileToArray(const char * fileName){
    FILE *file=fopen(fileName,"r");
    int numOfLines= numLines(fileName);
    float * arr= (float*)malloc(numOfLines*sizeof(float));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numOfLines;i++){
        fscanf(file,"%f\n",&arr[i]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return arr; 
}

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b){
    float fa= *(const float*) a;
    float fb= *(const float*) b;
    return (fa>fb)-(fa<fb);
}

int isSorted(FILE *fp){
    float prev;
    float o;
    do{
        fscanf(fp,"%f\n",&prev);
        fscanf(fp,"%f\n",&o);
        if(prev>o){
            fclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
    }while(fscanf(fp,"%f\n",&o)==1);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    const char *fileName1;
    const char *fileName2;
    const char *fileOut;
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    FILE *fp3;
    float *arr1;
    float *arr2;
    int size1;
    int size2;

    if(argc!=4){
        printf("Usage: fileSort.exe FILENAME1 FILENAME2 FILEOUT");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        fileName1= argv[1];
        fileName2= argv[2];
        fileOut= argv[3];
        fp1= fopen(fileName1,"r");
        fp2= fopen(fileName2, "r");
        fp3= fopen(fileOut, "w");
        if(fp1!=NULL && fp2!=NULL){
            arr1=fileToArray(fileName1);
            arr2=fileToArray(fileName2);
            size1=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(float);
            size2=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(float);
            if(!isSorted(fp1) || !isSorted(fp2)){
                printf("The files are not sorted in increasing order. Please sort them.");
            }
            else{
                float * arr3= malloc((size1+size2)*sizeof(float));
                int k;
                memcpy(arr3,arr1,size1*sizeof(float));
                memcpy(arr3+size1,arr2,size2*sizeof(float));
                qsort(arr3,size1+size2,sizeof(float),cmpfunc);
                for(k=0;k<(size1+size2);k++){
                    fprintf(fp3,"%f\n",arr3[k]);
                }
            }
            fclose(fp1);
            fclose(fp2);
            fclose(fp3);
        }
        else{
            printf("Files could not be opened\n");
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Two sample files for testing this code would be:

data1.txt:
0.586399
0.769484
0.864755
6.229683

data2.txt:
0.279828
0.309235
0.591884
0.962811
1.361349
10.203892
12.158343

The result should be their ordered combination. However, I get this as a result:
0.279828
0.309235
0.586399
0.769484

No matter what I change, it always writes four numbers into the resulting file. The helper functions seem to be doing their jobs just fine. It looks like the problem comes up when I'm trying to create the third array and fill it up (or at least I assume that's the source). I have no idea where this problem is coming from though. I would really appreciate some help on this issue.

Comment: There are various errors and flaws in your code, so _can_ result in undefined behaviour. Use a debugger, read the documentation of the functions and add error checking.

Comment: `size1=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(float);` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Rather than using three arrays, which provide sizing issues, why not read both files into a binary tree and then write the third file by doing an in-order traversal of the tree. The in-order traversal will result in the correct ordering of the values, and you will not need to worry about sorting and joining arrays.

Comment: @JimRogers: The checks for `isSorted()` in the code suggest that the two input files are supposed to be sorted, which *screams*  for a mergesort rather than building a cache-unfriendly tree.

Comment: @EOF: What does size1=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(float) do then? I read somewhere that I could use it to get the number of elements in an array. Is there a different functionality to it?

Comment: @EOF: The current code reads each file several times, which is far less efficient than the use of a tree.

Comment: @JimRogers: I don't know anything about these tree constructs you're talking about. Can you suggest a source for learning about them so that I can improve?

Comment: @Leopold2: http://www.learn-c.org/en/Binary_trees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `arr1` is not an array, it is a pointer to a float even though you are using it as pointer to the **first float element** in the array.

This means that sizeof will return to you the size of the pointer which is either 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending whether you are compiler 32-bit or 64-bit.

One way to fix this is to pull out the calculation of the number of lines like this:

```
int size1 = numLines(fileName1);
int size2 = numLines(fileName2);
arr1=fileToArray(fileName1, size1);
arr2=fileToArray(fileName2, size2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my issue completely.